# How to get an agent user capability in TFS Build task?

Tags: powershell, tfs, build, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I've declared a **user** capability named "MyCapability" in a TFS 2015 build agent with a path as value. How can I get this value in the powershell script of my build task ?

`$env:MyCapability` and `$MyCapability` don't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot access the capabilities from PowerShell through a variable unfortunately.

You could use the [Rest Client](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-restapi-samplecode) to connect back to TFS and read the Build Agent as well as the [Build Definition](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-restapi-samplecode/blob/master/VSTSRestApiSamples/Build2/Build.cs) to read out the configured values. This will require access to the OAuth token, which can be configured through a checkbox on the Build Definition's configuration page.

Comment: Can it be passed as parameters ? I know that, for example $(cmd) doesn't work but is there another way ?